# Splitting string array of one value fails

Tags: javascript

I have this:

```
var ID= "12,32,23,78";

var i = ID.split(',');
```

If I do this then it works fine, but when it is only one value like 12, then it gives me 0. How I can solve this issue? If I need to check for only one value, how do you do that?

Comment: When you say it is only 12 are you setting the variable like this: var ID = "12" or...  var ID = 12 - That would make a huge difference.

Comment: Yeap, haven't mentioned that ID could be an integer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
var i;
if (ID.indexOf(",") != -1)
    i = ID.split(',');
else
    i = ID;
```

Comment: This should work assuming ID always contains either a comma separated list of integer or a lone integer without a comma.

Comment: Except if ID is a **number** and not a string, then the call to `.search()` will fail.

Answer (score 6):

If the variable "ID" is the **number** 12, then of course it doesn't work — the `.split()` method is a method for strings, not numbers.  Try this:

```
var ID = /* whatever */;

var i = (ID + '').split(',');
```

Comment: +1.  Although the OP wasn't clear enough in his question, the other answers seem to be misunderstanding the inner workings of the *split()* method - if the separator character isn't in the string, *split()* will still work in exactly the same way - returning an array with only one element in it.

Comment: Yes, I realize it was pretty vague, and indeed I don't know what he means when he says "he give me 0" of course, but it's almost certainly what the problem is.

Comment: @Andy E: yup, though at least I found it suspicious that the split method was giving him 0, until Pointy clarified it was a data type thing. +1

Answer (score 0):

Exactly like what you posted except you check for the presence of the seperator with JavaScripts .indexOf() string method.

Comment: Won't work when the variable "ID" is set to a number instead of a string.

Answer (score 0):

```
String.prototype.mySplit = function(sep) {
    return (this.indexOf(sep) != -1) ? this.split(sep) : [this];
};
```

Example:

```
//var ID= '12,32,23,78';
var ID= '12';

//Update
if (typeof(ID)=='number') ID += '';

var i = ID.mySplit(',');

alert(i[0]);
```

Comment: This is completely unnecessary.  `"12".split(",")` will return `[ "12" ]` - you don't need to write a separate function to get this behavior.

Comment: You didn't mentioned that ID could be an integer, see updated code.

Answer (score 0):

```
    var ID= "12,32,23,78";

    var i = ID.split(',');

    will return [12,32,23,78]

    var ID= "12";

    var i = ID.split(',');

    will return [12] -- this is also an array
```

however you may do this

```
    var ID= "12";

    var i = ID.split(',') || ID;
```